# Android studio not allowing me to drag and drop widgets

Tags: java, android

I tried to drag a couple widgets onto the app page, but the widget wont show up on the app. All the current fixes with changing the theme and invalidating the caches do not work. I have just started the project, and have not touched any code yet.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is the cde you tried?

Answer (score 0):

change the state of layout from Text to Design.[image]

in Design state you can drag and drop widgets.